Can Linux OpenVPN server be accessed with Windows 10 Build-in VPN?
I have an OpenVPN server installed on Linux (Linux Wonderland 4.19.0-25-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.289-2 (2023-08-08) x86_64) and it works fine with OpenVPN client on Windows 10.
Is there a way to use build-in Windows 10 VPN client with Linux OpenVPN server? Can this be configured somehow?
If not, what other options do I have?

Cross posted at https://superuser.com/q/1849557/332907

@ChrisDavies, is something wrong with that?

@DamirTenishev Please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu/64073#64073

@ChanganAuto, thanks. My goal was to cover different audiences. Well, will do my best to follow.

The built-in Windows client doesn't support OpenVPN.
However it should be possible to use IPsec VPN to connect them. You'll need StrongSWAN (or a current alternative) on the Linux server.
(I've not done this myself so I can't give you specific implementation instructions. I have however successfully used IPsec IKEv1 between Linux servers and a Sophos/Draytek firewalls. Not easy.)

What makes Windows 10 built-in VPN client so special? I was sure both use some sets of underlying protocols which could have potentially overlap. I see that they don't, but what is the key "disagreement point" in these two?

There's overlap with IPsec, but that's not what you asked

Had I knew the answer, I would better shaped the question. So, are you saying that they have common protocols, but they are not enough to solve my task, namely to run VPN just on these shared parts?

@DamirTenishev I've updated my answer to reference IPsec

Thank you. Could you please glance at the How to install VPN on Linux Debian so that it could be used by built-in Windows 10 client?. Would the actions I list in my last comments do? I mean, should they be enough or this could be equally hard as in case you mentioned in the answer below. I mean, if I am not an expert in the area, is it a question of editing the registry and updating the configuration file or this is a long and hard way to go?

@DamirTenishev I don't know who downvoted your question. I can assure you that I did not, if that matters . But generally cross posting is frowned upon, as has already been explained
